# Ping test 8 times reply 8 times time-out

Tags: windows-7, windows

On my laption (Win 7) I'm running a VmWare Virtual machine Windows 7 with a network adapter in bridged mode because I wan't to be able to communicate between my host and my VM.

The host has IP 192.168.178.10 /255.255.255.0 / 192.168.178.1

The VM has IP 192.168.178.13 / 255.255.255.0 / 192.168.178.1

Now when I let both machines ping each other I notice a really strange thing. On both machines simultaneously I see 8 successful ping calls and then 8 time-outs this keeps on repeating... So it looks like the line is broken down

Not sure if its relevant but the laptop is connected to a wireless router. What I tried is  disabling firewall on both machines. On the VM adapter I also tried option replicate physical network state but behaviour was the same.

I've never seen this before so does anybody else have a clue where to look for this strange network behaviour? Thanks

Comment: I've seen this before when there are two possible routes between the machines to send packets over and one of the routes failing.

Comment: Hi Lucas, how would you start troubleshooting this?

Comment: @ponsfonze sure it does if you set it up to listen for inbound traffic for file and printer sharing (ICMP) And I have no idea what's the relevance because I've specified I turned WF off and it didn't matter. (and after this post I notice ponsfonze deleted his comment...)

Comment: I would try setting up wireshark on both machines and see if you can receive incoming packets.

Comment: @ponsfonze thanks but I can receive packets but as said above they are toggling on and off because the traffic is being cut or something. When the pings are successful I can also go to the disk of the other pc for example

Comment: Now I would try and look where the failing packets are going.

Comment: If we can figure out where the failed packets are going, it might give us a clue to what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking at wire shark for quite some time and I was not able to spot a pattern of info to help me forward!

While I was doing this I thought why not switch the network adapter to NAT. As a test I did this and it totally solved this problem. both machines are pinging each other now without interrupts...

This has been one of those.... O well thanks for thinking with me!